# Can I use API to Automate Posting Tracking Numbers to orders?

Tags: api, tracking, fedex, ups

We ship using FEDEX and UPS, and we never found a need to post the tracking number to the payment record, however, recently a customer did a charge-back and the claim was that the order was not shipped even though it was. The tracking number was not entered into paypal, but we do have a tracking number for this order. Do we need to manually enter **every** tracking number into Paypal, or do we have a chance to enter it after a chargeback attempt has been made?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal's standard API does not provide a field for tracking numbers in their order details, so there is no way to automatically send PayPal this information for all orders.

Their API supports disputes, so it could be possible, however it looks like it could be very messy. The workflow would look like this:

1. Use PayPal's *Customer Disputes API* to GET all disputes with a **dispute_state** of **REQUIRED_ACTION** and **reason** of **MERCHANDISE_OR_SERVICE_NOT_RECEIVED**. Save the Order ID
2. Cross reference the Order ID with your order management software's API to get a tracking number. If the tracking number exists,
3. Use *PayPal's Customer Disputes API* to escalate the dispute to a claim and save the returned claim API endpoint.
4. The documentation gets a little fuzzy here and may require some contact ith PayPal's support team, but it looks like you should be able to POST evidence to the claim with **PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT**,  which includes *tracking_number* and *carrier_name*.

Unless you are processing a high volume of these missing order claims it probably won't make sense to go through all this legwork. If it truly is taking a lot of time and energy for you or your staff to handle this specific type of PayPal dispute then maybe it would be worthwhile. I might also suggest in this case to start toggling the "signature required" settings for your shipping partners.